# Remove columns using shell commands

Tags: bash, shell, text, awk, sed

I have some big txt files as an inputs which looks like

```
# USER_IP: 37.1.62.12 INTERFACE CHARMM-GUI
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
lig.pdb
54 56 1 0 0
SMALL
NO_CHARGES


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 CAA         2.9880    0.1910   12.9830 C.3       1 P0G    0.0000
      2 CAB         1.3730    1.7370   10.6500 C.3       1 P0G    0.0000
      3 CAC        -0.5820    0.2000   10.5350 C.3       1 P0G    0.0000
      4 OAD        -5.1220    5.7850    8.9220 O.2       1 P0G    0.0000
      5 OAE        -2.7610    6.1960    4.9010 O.3       1 P0G    0.0000
      6 OAF        -0.8620    0.4430    6.3540 O.3       1 P0G    0.0000
      7 CAG         0.7160   -2.5530   14.2490 C.ar      1 P0G    0.0000
      8 CAH         0.1300   -3.0010   13.0720 C.ar      1 P0G    0.0000
```

...

```
here in each of file I have a lot of strings:
      6 OAF        -0.8620    0.4430    6.3540 O.3       1 P0G    0.0000
      7 CAG         0.7160   -2.5530   14.2490 C.ar      1 P0G    0.0000
      8 CAH         0.1300   -3.0010   13.0720 C.ar      1 P0G    0.0000
```

my task is using some Linux shell script and combination of AFK, SED to remove all columns from those fragments with the exception of first 1-5 columns which are relevant for me. So the example file after its processing should be like

```
# USER_IP: 37.1.62.12 INTERFACE CHARMM-GUI
@<TRIPOS>MOLECULE
lig.pdb
54 56 1 0 0
SMALL
NO_CHARGES


@<TRIPOS>ATOM
      1 CAA         2.9880    0.1910   12.9830 
      2 CAB         1.3730    1.7370   10.6500 
      3 CAC        -0.5820    0.2000   10.5350 
      4 OAD        -5.1220    5.7850    8.9220 
      5 OAE        -2.7610    6.1960    4.9010 
      6 OAF        -0.8620    0.4430    6.3540 
      7 CAG         0.7160   -2.5530   14.2490 
      8 CAH         0.1300   -3.0010   13.0720
```

the problem here that always in same type of files I have several strings (its number might differ) before those segments which should be processed. So the only idea is to use below string

```
@<TRIPOS>ATOM
```

as the reference and start to count strings which columns must be processed only after  this reference string

I'd be thankful for several examples and its short explanation

Gleb

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk 4.0 or later:

```
gawk 'flag { split($0, f, " ", d); for(i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) printf("%s%s", d[i - 1], f[i]); print ""; next } /@<TRIPOS>ATOM/ { flag = 1 } 1' filename
```

Most of this is to keep the formatting intact; if the formatting does not matter, then

```
awk 'flag { NF = 5 } /@<TRIPOS>ATOM/ { flag = 1 } 1' filename
```

is a simpler way that works with older gawk and mawk as well. To make this work with BSD awk,

```
awk 'flag { NF = 5; $1 = $1 } /@<TRIPOS>ATOM/ { flag = 1 } 1' filename
```

is necessary (`$1 = $1` just to force the rebuilding of the line). Thanks to @tripleee for commenting on this.

The second piece of code simply adjusts the number of fields, causing the line to be rebuilt with less of them. The first does a bit more:

```
flag {                              # if we're already processing lines
  split($0, f, " ", d)              # split line into array f, save delimiters
                                    # into array d

  for(i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {         # print the first five fields separated
    printf("%s%s", d[i - 1], f[i])  # by the saved delimiters
  }
  print ""                          # add newline
  next                              # that is all.
}
                                    # if we're not processing lines yet
/@<TRIPOS>ATOM/ { flag = 1 }        # check if we should, and if so set flag
1                                   # then print line unchanged.
```

**Addendum:** Another way that also preserves the formatting is to use sed:

```
sed '1,/@<TRIPOS>ATOM/ ! { s/\b[[:space:]]/\n/5; s/\n.*//; }' filename
```

That is:

```
1,/@<TRIPOS>ATOM/ ! {     # For those lines that are not in the range from
                          # the beginning to the first line containing
                          # @<TRIPOS>ATOM

  s/\b[[:space:]]/\n/5    # place a newline after the fifth column
  s/\n.*//                # then remove the newline and everything after it
}
```

This should work with both GNU sed and BSD sed. Since `\b` is not part of POSIX basic regexes, though, more esoteric seds may require a slight change:

```
sed '1,/@<TRIPOS>ATOM/ ! { s/\([^[:space:]]\)[[:space:]]/\1\n/5; s/\n.*//; }' filename
```

This works essentially the same way but uses a different regex to recognize the end of columns.

Comment: I was not successful with setting `NF = 5` on OS X awk. It would be nice if it worked, but it doesn't seem to work portably.

Comment: Does it work if you set `NF = 5` and `$1 = $1`? I suspect the line rebuild isn't triggered in BSD awk just by setting `NF`, but we really want to set `NF` to avoid superfluous field separators at the end of the output.

Comment: Setting NF will have no effect at all in some awks, regardless of whether or not you reassign $1 to itself, e.g. on Solaris: `echo "1 2 3" | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{NF=2;$1=$1}1'` outputs `1 2 3`.

Comment: The gawk split() feature is neat.  Absent that, I think the formatting could be preserved with `printf "%7s%4s%15s%10s%10s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5; next` instead of `NF = 5`.

Answer (score -1):

The following should work:

```
sed -n '/@<TRIPOS>ATOM/,$p' filename | tail -n +2 | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1-5
```

Work as follows:

1. Print only the lines after the `@<TRIPOS>ATOM`:

   ```
   sed -n '/@<TRIPOS>ATOM/,$p' filename
   ```
2. Omit the first line (which contains `@<TRIPOS>ATOM` and you don't want that):

   ```
   tail -n +2
   ```
3. Squeeze the extra spaces between columns:

   ```
   tr -s " "
   ```
4. `cut` the columns using space as the delimiter, grab the fields you need:

   ```
   cut -d" " -f1-5
   ```

Comment: -One This removes the header completely.  The header should be retained, and columns adjusted only after the "tripos" line.